# How can i use admin interface to manage datebases from different database?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This is my first ask on Stackoverflow. If there is anything went wrong, please tell me. Thank you very much!!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface

I followed the django official documents, but still can't work at all.

In shell, it can show data from different databases, this means router work nicely.

But it can't work in admin site. 
[image captures here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jOOR.png)

Or raise "LookupError" "No installed app with label 'insight'." when i changed from

```
othersite.register(CrawlerIndex, CrawlerIndexAdmin)
```

to

```
admin.site.register(CrawlerIndex, CrawlerIndexAdmin)
```

in admin.py

Here's my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import MonitorCrawlers, CrawlerIndex

# Register your models here.
admin.autodiscover()

class MultiDBModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # A handy constant for the name of the alternate database.

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Tell Django to save objects to the 'other' database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the 'other' database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

class MultiDBModelAdmin2(MultiDBModelAdmin):
    using = 'insight_db'

class MonitorCrawlersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class CrawlerIndexAdmin(MultiDBModelAdmin2):
    pass

othersite = admin.AdminSite('insight_db')
othersite.register(CrawlerIndex, CrawlerIndexAdmin)

admin.site.register(MonitorCrawlers, MonitorCrawlersAdmin)
```

and part of `setting.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'table',
    'table.templatetags.extfilter',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {
    'insight': 'insight_db',
}
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myapp1',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.73',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'insight_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'crawler',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.73',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['table.db_router.InsightRouter',]
```

and `InsightRouter.py`

```
class InsightRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    insight_db application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read insight_db models go to insight_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'insight':
            return 'insight_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write insight_db models go to insight_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'insight':
            return 'insight_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the insight_db app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'insight' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'insight_db':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the insight_db app only appears in the 'insight_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'insight':
            return db == 'insight_db'
        return None
```

and `models.py`

```
class CrawlerIndex(models.Model):

    blahblahblah


    class Meta:
        app_label = 'insight'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'crawler_index'
```